# User Feed page in Google Chrome

Tags: bug, status-declined, google-chrome

The "user feed" page is not rendering properly in Google Chrome (V 3.0.195.25). It looks like a text file with all the html tags and contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome has no support for RSS feeds.

Comment: and, it *still* doesn't, almost 10 versions later!

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I'm not really sure it ever will. There's a plugin for that.

Comment: STOP THE PRESS! IT NOW WORKS IN CHROME 13! Jinx! No seriously!

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Are you serious? I'm using the dev build but I didn't even see that... I see mass hysteria ahead!